# Android- Tabbed View on a navigation view

Tags: android

i want to add a tabbed view on my home fragment .... 
can anyone help me on how to add tabbed view ..i am using navigation view
here's the code

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    View homeView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);

       return homeView;
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFrame, new HomeFragment()).commit();

            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_appointment_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFrame, new ApptFragment()).commit();    

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_record_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFrame, new RecordFragment()).commit();    

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFrame, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_groom_layout) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFrame, new GroomFragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_boarding_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFrame, new MedicalHistory()).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) homeView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? what you want ? you just posted the code of a sample navigation drawer activity

Comment: yup i would like to have a tabbed view in homefragment

Comment: no one will code for you here as long as you dont post what you have tried

Comment: go through this and try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

then post what went wrong so we can help

Comment: oh thanks.. i am sorry ..

Comment: try this ]http://stackoverflow.com/a/34918779/5188159